# Not able to configure Idea-3g NetSetter in RHEL 6.1,System is taking it as mass staorage not as modem

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have installed Redhat(not purchased) 6.1 (New Redhat) and i am trying to connect Idea-3g NetSetter in it. I have already installed ppp & wvdial by Yum and have made necessary changes in /etc/wvdial.conf file But i am not able to configure it.

When i went through logs,i found my system is taking this device as mass staorge device  & not taking it as a modem device.I went google but it also doesnt help me

In Wvdial.conf file i have to make an entry of /dev/ttyUSB0 but there is no file like ttyUSB under dev directory.There is tty1,tty2 etc. So how i can resolve this problem.Kindly help me..Some nessary infomration are here

```
[root@server ~]# wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
--> Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[root@server ~]# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552 (HSPA modem)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:643d Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[root@server ~]#vi /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.i686 (mockbuild@x86-001.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 10 15:42:28 EDT 2011 



[root@server ~]# tail /var/log/messages  (Last Few Lines)
May  4 22:49:18 server kernel: usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, address 6
May  4 22:49:18 server kernel: scsi 15:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
May  4 22:49:19 server gnome-keyring-daemon[2212]: removing removable location: /media/20110811_0533
May  4 22:49:19 server gnome-keyring-daemon[2212]: no volume registered at: /media/20110811_0533
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1446
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: usb 1-1.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: scsi17 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
May  4 22:49:31 server kernel: scsi18 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
May  4 22:49:36 server kernel: scsi 17:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May  4 22:49:36 server kernel: scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
May  4 22:49:36 server kernel: sr1: scsi-1 drive
May  4 22:49:36 server kernel: sr 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
May  4 22:49:36 server kernel: sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
May  4 22:49:36 server kernel: sd 18:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk


[root@server ~]# cd /dev/
[root@server dev]# ls
agpgart          log                 ram1    sda5      tty15  tty40  tty9
autofs           loop0               ram10   sda6      tty16  tty41  ttyS0
block            loop1               ram11   sda7      tty17  tty42  ttyS1
bsg              loop2               ram12   sda8      tty18  tty43  ttyS2
bus              loop3               ram13   sdb       tty19  tty44  ttyS3
cdrom            loop4               ram14   sdc       tty2   tty45  urandom
cdrom2           loop5               ram15   sg0       tty20  tty46  usbmon0
cdrw             loop6               ram2    sg1       tty21  tty47  usbmon1
char             loop7               ram3    sg2       tty22  tty48  usbmon2
console          lp0                 ram4    sg3       tty23  tty49  v4l
core             lp1                 ram5    sg4       tty24  tty5   vcs
cpu              lp2                 ram6    shm       tty25  tty50  vcs1
cpu_dma_latency  lp3                 ram7    snapshot  tty26  tty51  vcs2
crash            MAKEDEV             ram8    snd       tty27  tty52  vcs3
disk             mapper              ram9    sr0       tty28  tty53  vcs4
dri              mcelog              random  sr1       tty29  tty54  vcs5
dvd              mem                 raw     stderr    tty3   tty55  vcs6
dvdrw            net                 rfkill  stdin     tty30  tty56  vcsa
fb               network_latency     root    stdout    tty31  tty57  vcsa1
fb0              network_throughput  rtc     systty    tty32  tty58  vcsa2
fd               null                rtc0    tty       tty33  tty59  vcsa3
full             nvram               scd0    tty0      tty34  tty6   vcsa4
fuse             oldmem              scd1    tty1      tty35  tty60  vcsa5
hpet             port                sda     tty10     tty36  tty61  vcsa6
hugepages        ppp                 sda1    tty11     tty37  tty62  vga_arbiter
hvc0             ptmx                sda2    tty12     tty38  tty63  video0
input            pts                 sda3    tty13     tty39  tty7   watchdog
kmsg             ram0                sda4    tty14     tty4   tty8   zero





 [root@server dev]#vi /etc/wvdial.congf

[Dialer Defaults]
Modem=/dev/ttyUSB0        ***what to write here***
Baud = 115200
Init 1 = AT+CGMM
Init 2 = AT+CMEE=1
Init 3 = ATE0
Init 4 = AT^HS=0,0
Init 5 = AT+CFUN?
Init 6 = AT+CLCK="SC",2
Init 7 = AT+CPIN?
Init 8 = AT+CLCK="SC",2
Modem Type = USB MODEM
Phone=*99#
Username =""
Password =""
New PPPD = yes
Dial Command=ATDT
Stupid Mode=1
ISDN=0
```

**Kindly help me How i can troubleshoot it,Where & what changes should i made so that rhel 6 can take it as modem not a mass staorage device if i am thinking right**

---

I am Giving output of wvdial coomand,it is restarting again and again and **showing ppd error 16**.I tried to figure out it and founf this error is for modem hang.I tried a lot but problem is as it is.

```
[root@server ~]# wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Sat May  5 07:25:25 2012
--> Pid of pppd: 2905
--> Using interface ppp0
--> Disconnecting at Sat May  5 07:25:27 2012
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Sat May  5 07:25:32 2012
--> Pid of pppd: 2925
--> Using interface ppp0
--> Disconnecting at Sat May  5 07:25:34 2012
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 10 seconds



[root@server ~]# vi /dev/tty
tty                tty25              tty42              tty6
tty0               tty26              tty43              tty60
tty1               tty27              tty44              tty61
tty10              tty28              tty45              tty62
tty11              tty29              tty46              tty63
tty12              tty3               tty47              tty7
tty13              tty30              tty48              tty8
tty14              tty31              tty49              tty9
tty15              tty32              tty5               ttyS0
tty16              tty33              tty50              ttyS1
tty17              tty34              tty51              ttyS2
tty18              tty35              tty52              ttyS3
tty19              tty36              tty53              ttyUSB3
tty2               tty37              tty54              ttyUSB4
tty20              tty38              tty55              ttyUSB_utps_diag
tty21              tty39              tty56              ttyUSB_utps_modem
tty22              tty4               tty57              ttyUSB_utps_pcui
tty23              tty40              tty58              
tty24              tty41              tty59
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common for such devices to first present themselves as a mass storage device, probably containing documentation and drivers.

Try [ejecting](http://eject.sourceforge.net/) the mass storage device first. The real modem device will probably turn up.

**Automating this**

Once you confirm that this is indeed the problem you can automate the ejection.

It's described reasonably well in [this forum discussion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/wvdial-problem-911225/), but in short you add a udev rule which calls eject or usb-modeswitch as soon as the device is detected. 
That way the correct device node will be created and you don't need to worry about the problem in WvDial.

Comment: Means you want to say should i unmont it first and then try again..Link given by you not working sir...

Comment: No, not unmount. Eject. It's a specific ioctl() call. (Sorry about the bad link, it was the one the debian package specified. I've fixed it now.)

Comment: Sure i will try this one now sir,but one thing is in my mind,until or unless i dont mention device name in /etc/wvdial.conf file like /dev/ttyUSB0, it is not going to work..NOw i think main question is this how make this device behave like modem and what entry should be there in wvdial.conf file

Comment: Dear Sir..I tried to eject data card but nothing happen..One thing i noticed now i am able to see ttyUSB3,ttyUSB4,ttyUSB_utps_modem IN dev but these are also not working...I am giving some output here

Comment: I'd hardly call that nothing! That's exactly what I said would happen, and exactly what you needed too.

Comment: Dear Sir, yaa u right not i am able to see entries in /dev/ttyUSB but when i am dialing wvdial it is connecting disconnecting and showing error 16(modem hang and u need to configure wvdial.conf file again..In next post down i pasted what i am getting sir.Thanks for ur support

Comment: Perhaps I was too subtle in my previous comment. When I asked you to look at /var/log/messages that was also a suggestion to *post* that information. We are not mind readers. Neither do we have a crystal ball. We have no more information than you give us. If you don't give us any we can't help you! (Also make sure to check that the pppd output really ends up in /var/log/messages and not in /var/log/daemon.log or something.)